# How to remove specific pages from word document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

i am using `vb.net` and I have a word document that I am editing.

I want to remove the page break only from page 6 (for example ) to the end of the document and not from the entire document.

The code I have is for the entire document - How should I change it?

```
Dim paragraphs As Word.Paragraphs
paragraphs = doc.Paragraphs

For Each paragraph As Word.Paragraph In paragraphs
    If paragraph.Range.Text.Trim() = String.Empty Then
        paragraph.Range.[Select]()
        wordapp.Selection.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. This will delete the pagebreak (if exists) from the 6th Page.

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim wrdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    '~~> Page NO
    Dim pgNo As Integer = 6
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Document1.docx")

        '~~> Display Word
        wrdApp.Visible = True

        With wrdDoc
            For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
                If Asc(.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text) = 12 And _
                   .Paragraphs(i).Range.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber) = pgNo Then
                    .Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete()
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The above code is tested and tried :) Did you set the page number in this line `Dim pgNo As Integer = 6`

Comment: yes but the issue is that i need from page 6 to the end of the document. i tried to do this without success:                                                           With doc
                For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If (Asc(.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text) = 12 And (.Paragraphs(i).Range.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber) > PageNumberToStart)) Then
                        .Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete()
                    End If
                Next i
            End With

Comment: Oh then amend the code in the loop. Change `= pgNo` to `>= pgNo`. Leave everything as it is